# Gnuplot - Iteration with two commands

Tags: iteration, gnuplot

I'm trying to build a sort of bar-chart using a simple data file (`.example`) containing only 0s or 1s. Here is the data contained in `.example`:

```
dest    P1 P2 P3 P4 P5  NA
D1  0 1 1 0 0  0
D2  0 0 1 0 0  0 
D3  0 1 0 1 0  0 
""
GPV 1 1 1 1 1  1
```

and here is the code I'm using:

```
set style histogram rowstacked title textcolor lt -1
set datafile missing 'nan'
set style data histograms

plot '.example' using ( $2==0 ? 1 : 0 ) ls 17 title 'NA', \
'' using ( $2==1 ? 1 : 0 ) ls 1, \
for [i=3:5] '.example' using ( column(i)==0 ? 1 : 0) ls 17 notitle, \
for [i=3:5] '' using ( column(i)==1 ? 1 : 0) ls i-1
```

where the last two commands iterate over a potentially large number of
columns stacking white or colored boxes depending on the value of `column(i)`. To keep the same color order among different columns in the histogram I would need to merge the two iterations into a single one with two commands.

Is it possible? Any suggestion on how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use nested loops, which I think is what you want to achieve. You can use an outer loop iterating over your large number of columns and an inner loop iterating over the two options (white vs. colored), `for [i=3:5] for [j=0:1]`, and tell gnuplot to ignore the column if its content doesn't match the value of `j` using `1/0` (or use the trick, valid for histograms, of setting it to `0` as you're already doing):

```
set style histogram rowstacked title textcolor lt -1
set datafile missing 'nan'
set style data histograms

plot '.example' using ( $2==0 ? 1 : 0 ) ls 17 title 'NA', \
'' using ( $2==1 ? 1 : 0 ) ls 1, \
for [i=3:5] for [j=0:1] '.example' using ( column(i) == j ? 1 : 0 ) \
ls ( j == 0 ? 17 : i-1 ) notitle
```

The code above is equivalent to what you have already, only the value of `j` allows to switch the style depending on whether you have a `0` or a `1` as the column's value.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. Your proposed solution would have been perfect to me but actually 'column' can only be used with 'using' and not with 'ls' or 'title' specifications. Also the nested loop does not really help since as you correctly understood I need to specify the 'ls' based on the 0 or 1 read in the data.

Comment: Sorry, I could not test the command because you did not post a sample data file (try next time to do that). I'll fix my answer with a different solution.

Comment: Also, in the future, try reducing your question to the minimum related to the actual issue, for instance removing the plotting of the other files that you have in your example. This makes it more likely to attract somebody's attention since less time and effort is required for us to read and understand the problem.

Comment: Thanks Miguel and sorry for my sloppiness. I'm going to edit my question following your suggestions.

Comment: Great, that's exactly what I needed. I had to make a very minor adjustment for the 'title' command. Thanks again for your help.